# wordpress: generating pages via database

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have made some research and discover that when I create a page on WordPress the table wp_post and wp_postmeta generate a row on wp_post a determined number of rows for wp_postmeta depends on the plugins and settings you have.

But when I tried to generate a page adding these rows imported via a file (CSV format) WordPress don't generate the page.

When I click to saw this page the page returns me a 404 error. Anyone can tell what I am doing wrong?

I want to generate 100 pages via database because doing this manually is insane. I had done this importing via CSV file format but if anybody can tell a better way to do that that will be great.

Comment: Never manually change the WP database. That's just asking for trouble. Wordpress provides functions to programmatically add pages.

Comment: Thank for you answer  i understand how to do it know